# Chrome devtools hangs when loading angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I have a quite large angular (1.5) app which i'm experiencing some weirdness with.
If I have chrome devtools open while loading the app that chrome tab runs on 100% cpu and take a minute or so to load. Memory usage will also run crazy high, up to 500 mb, once loaded everything but 150mb will get garbage collected.

After the app has loaded it runs just fine.
If i load the app without devtools open it takes a second or two.

Memory usage seems stable during usage.
I have eliminated the largest ngRepeats with custom repeaters so my watch count is ok.

Tried on several computers/operating systems.
Tried with no chrome extensions.

This is a chrome only problem. (or at least not safari)

So, do a timeline profile you say? The weirdest thing of all is that the problem goes away if I try to record a timeline profile.

Anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Can only comment if we see the issue happening live. :(

Comment: Do you have any chrome plugins related to Angularjs which may cause the problem?

Comment: Give a list of plugins and link some of our repeats. Do you have any watches on some of the code?

Comment: @RobinvanderKnaap Problem is there with zero plugins.

Comment: Maybe check the network tab to see if a lot of calls are made?

Comment: @lisap. Yes, but why would having the devtools open matter?

Comment: My guess would be that devtools have some overhead processing calls and displaying them (in a way that extensive logging can also slow down). Like @McBoman mentioned, watches can slow down as well (check http://www.alexkras.com/11-tips-to-improve-angularjs-performance/)

Comment: Yeah, think I read all articles there are on angular performance. I have close to no repeats and use one-time bindings where ever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that DevTools are fetching source files from the page during load or something like that.

When timeline recording is active DevTools disable most of its debugging functions, that's why it runs faster.

Comment: Sounds like a valid explanation.